# Association rules - Find 100% confidence rules

Tags: data-mining, data-science-model, mathematics, association-rules, confidence

> Suppose there are 100 items, numbered 1 to 100, and also 100 baskets, also numbered 1 to 100. Item `i` is in basket `b` if and only if `i` divides `b` with no remainder. Thus, item 1 is in all the baskets, item 2 is in all fifty of the even-numbered baskets, etc. For example Basket 12 consists of items {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}.

> (a) Describe all the association rules that have 100% confidence. Give an example.

I'm really new to Data-Science stuff, so I have no idea how to find a mathematical expression describing all such association rules.

Can someone find such an expression?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. For homework questions please provide your attempt and/or explain your difficulty.